# Zero (0) compatible devices on Google Play

Tags: android, android-manifest, licensing, android-library, incompatibility

Every time I upload my app to Google Play, I get "0 compatible devices". My app works when I test it on my device, and I`m not using anything that would require a specific device.

There is not reason for this to happen, my app is very simple.

My Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gameblox.gocil"
android:versionCode="6"
android:versionName="1.5">

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21" android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<!-- Required to access Google Play Licensing -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

<!-- Required to download files from Google Play -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Required to keep CPU alive while downloading files (NOT to keep screen awake) -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!--
     Required to poll the state of the network connection
    and respond to changes
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Required to check whether Wi-Fi is enabled -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<!-- Required to read and write the com.gameblox.gocil.expansion files on shared storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name=".SampleAlarmReceiver"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WebviewActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_webview" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

When I click with Ctrl on

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
```

Android Studio can't find that library... and the others show as well...

What am I doing wrong? =/